# How to run flash from android application

Tags: android, flash, jar, sdk, air

I am trying to create an application that can read "swf" flash file 
but it is not working in may app.

Is there any JAR/library that I should include in my project to run my "swf" file smoothly.

My Code :

```
   WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbMyView);
   WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
   ws.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
   ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
   wv.loadUrl("http://www.myWeb.com/myFlash/file1.swf");
```

Please any one can help me.

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);` 
 is a *deprecated* method try targeting min SDK version 8 (2.2) and setting `webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);`

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState).)

Comment: this Code can't run the flash on my android application

Comment: but method getSettings() is undefined for the type WebSettings

Comment: i think the problem here because android need a flash plug in whit the application